# Passing parameter to subquery

Tags: .net, t-sql, ado.net, subquery, strongly-typed-dataset

Now this one is driving me mad. It gets as simple as trying to add a new query to my `QueriesTableAdapter` (typed `DataSet`) and assigning it a query that takes a parameter in the SUBQUERY; something like:

```
SELECT CONVERT(bit, CASE WHEN (SELECT ROUND(SUM(Amount), 2) FROM  [Transaction]
       WHERE UserID = @UserID) >= 9.99 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

The wizard returns `must declare scalar variable @UserID`.

I've been working with ADO.NET for over 8 years now, but haven't noticed this problem before. I have recently upgraded to SQL Server 2012 Express; maybe something to do with that?

**MORE INFO**

I just resolved the problem at hand (like all good devs) by removing the subquery, like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(bit, CASE WHEN ROUND(SUM(Amount), 2) >= 9.99 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    FROM [Transaction] WHERE (UserID = @UserID)
```

but this doesn't address the actual concern, passing a param to subquery. I further found that I can't use a parameter even in `CASE` clause. For example, if I'd rather avoid hardcoding the price (9.99) in the query and replace it with a varible, but doing so raises the same error as above.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found a workaround. It is not pretty but it works. I'd welcome anything that is better than this and doesn't need Stored Procs.

It appears that `TableAdapter` reads query parameters from the `WHERE` clause only (probably to infer their types), so if you could introduce your variable in `WHERE` too, using an always-true condition of course, it would work. Something like:

```
SELECT CONVERT(bit, CASE WHEN ROUND(SUM(Amount), 2) >= @Price THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    FROM [Transaction] WHERE UserID = @UserID AND (Amount <= @Price OR Amount > @Price)
```

That last part of the `WHERE` clause is there to simply introduce the @Price variable and to define its type and has no effect on results. Hopefully SQL Server query optimizers will truncate this part before executing the query.